# Javascript: Why name object method functions

Tags: javascript

In some projects I can see, that the functions wich are object methods get names after the function constructor - I can not see why, can any one explain?

Example: named

```
someObj.prototype = {
        load: function someObj_load(file) {
```

vs unnamed

```
someObj.prototype = {
        load: function(file) {
```

I can not see any advantage in the above.

Comment: Maybe for recursive call of the function. You will be able to reuse the name

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/javascript-function-declaration-syntax-var-fn-function-vs-function-fn

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you can see the name of the function name instead of Anonymous function in stack traces. I think some browsers will pick up the name of the variable/attribute you've assigned it to. Some don't.